# Model binding in Ajax call with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My action method used to have one parameter, and I didn't have any problem to pass model to it.

```
public ActionResult actionMethod([Bind(Exclude = "pro1, pro2")] Class model)
```

And the Ajax call:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("actionMethod", "controller")",
    method: 'post',
    data: { header: formData},
    success: function (result) {
        .....
    }
});
```

It worked fine, until I had to add another parameter to the method:

```
public ActionResult actionMethod([Bind(Exclude = "pro1, pro2")] Class model, string anotherParam = "1")
```

And I'm trying with this Ajax call:

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("actionMethod", "controller")",
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        header: formData,
        anotherParam: '1'
    },
    success: function (result) {
        .....
    }
});
```

And it doesn't work anymore, the model is always null. How should I pass these data?

Comment: On option would be just `formData += '&anotherParam=1` and then `data: formData,` but using FormData is a better aproach. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) and in particular the last code snippet for adding extra data

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I have another not much related question too: I have to put elements of this model in different places, so there are other controls between them. currently, I just use `form` to serialize them. But I might have other forms too, do I have any better option?

Comment: Do you mean you have multiple forms on the same page and you want to serialize and post them all?

Comment: Yes, and I want them to be bound in one model!

Comment: You can still use FormData - perhaps just select all `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements and using a `$.each()` get the `name` attribute (`var name = $(this).attr('name');`) and value (`var value = $(this).val();`) and append each one - `formdata.append(name, value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the best way, but following will make it work.

Pass the form data as usual in the `'data'` parameter of `ajax`, and put the extra parameter in the `query string` of url.

```
var formData = $('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("actionMethod", "controller", new { anotherParam = 1})',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        header: formData
    },
    success: function (result) {
        .....
    }
});
```